# Menu List Overflow HTML (also within iframe)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

The main issue is that menu items are overflowing off the page to the bottom. I have attempted to solve the issue and I have failed to do so and I really have burnt myself out trying to fix it. This menu is in an iframe but regardless the problem still occurs even if it is on a regular page. A picture of the problem is below:

[image]

Here is the code

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="roleMenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <ul id="menuUL" class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li{{ (Request::is('admin') ? ' class="active"' : '') }}><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                        <li{{ (Request::is('admin/blogs*') ? ' class="active"' : '') }}><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Pages</a></li>
                        <li{{ (Request::is('admin/comments*') ? ' class="active"' : '') }}><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></span> Comments</a></li>
                        <li{{ (Request::is('admin/menuBuilder*') ? ' class="active"' : '') }}><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></span> Menu Builder</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown{{ (Request::is('admin/users*|admin/roles*') ? ' active' : '') }}">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="{{{ URL::to('admin/users') }}}">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Users <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li{{ (Request::is('admin/users*') ? ' class="active"' : '') }}><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Users</a></li>
                                <li{{ (Request::is('admin/roles*') ? ' class="active"' : '') }}><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Roles</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                        <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('/') }}}">View Homepage</a></li>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                                <a  class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {{{ Auth::user()->username }}}   <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu " style="overflow:scroll"; >
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/settings') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> A</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/logout') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> B</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/settings') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> C</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/logout') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> d</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/settings') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> e</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/logout') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> f</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/settings') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> g</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/logout') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> h</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/settings') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> i</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/logout') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> j</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/settings') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> k</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/logout') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> l</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/settings') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> m</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/logout') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> n</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/settings') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> o</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/logout') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> p</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/settings') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> q</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/logout') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> r</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/settings') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> s</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/logout') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> t</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/settings') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> u</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/logout') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> v</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/settings') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> w</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/logout') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> x</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/settings') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> y</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{{ URL::to('user/logout') }}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> z</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>

                                </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Multiple approaches taken:

1) Setting overflow:scroll to dropdown class:

**Result:** It works but not ideal at all.

[image]

2) Setting overflow:scroll to dropdown-menu class:

**Result:** A scroll bar appears but doesn't do anything(aka scrolling doesn't work)

[image]

3) Attempted to do solution here. If I change up the html or css to make it compatible it ruins other stuff already made and looks terrible. If anyone could help me with this I would greatly appreciate it.

More information to help:
  My code is based on a laravel starter kit: https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site

I been at this for a few hours doing research and nothing for this seems like an easy solution, mainly because of the way my menu bar is structured. Anyone willing to provide help, css, javascript, or anything else that can help me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should set height to dropdown-menu class , otherwise 'overflow:auto' won't work